# JSoup Getting Text Without Wrapping Tag Under an Element

Tags: java, html, jsoup

How do I get the following 'Some random text', and wrap it with a span?

e.g. I have the following element :

```html
<div>
    Some random text 1
    <a href="some_url">Go to Link</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Some random text 2</span>
    <a href="some_url">Go to Link</a>
</div>
```

And I would have something like this :

```html
<div>
    <span>Some random text 1</span>
    <a href="some_url">Go to Link</a>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Some random text 2</span>
    <a href="some_url">Go to Link</a>
</div>
```

You see, some divs are already wrapped with span, and some aren't. I want to wrap only those that haven't been wrapped.

Comment: I updated my answer according to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick solution may help you. I tested it using jsoup v1.12.1

Firstly find all elements by `div` tag, without the `span`:

```java
   List<Element> elements = jsoupDocument
            .getElementsByTag("div")
            .stream()
            .filter(div -> div.getElementsByTag("span").isEmpty())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then iterate through found elements and update them wrapping its text within `span` tag:

```java
    elements.forEach(div -> {
        // dissect element
        String text = div.ownText();
        Elements children = div.children();

        // clear any existing inner HTML and replace it with an empty String.
        div.text("");

        // put all elements back together and wrap the div text with the span tag
        div.prepend(String.format("<span>%s</span>", text));
        children.forEach(div::appendChild);
    });

    LOG.info(jsoupDocument.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, Eduardo, I didn't ask properly the last time. I updated my question. Thank you for your response